# Magento & Google Analytics - Tracking Code or Google API?

Tags: magento-1.9, google-analytics, google-api

Is there any difference between using the **Google Analytics Tracking Code** or using the inbuilt **Google API** analytics section in Magento?

Using the Google API section seems 'neater' as I don't have to copy & paste code into my site.  I assume Magento inserts this code automatically once configured.

I just wondered if there was much difference in terms of usability and features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which version of Magento you are using. The new Universal Analytics Code is only available since version 1.9.1.0.

1.9.0.1 on the other hand only had the old code, which made it a pain to add any multiple event tracking.

So, if you're on 1.9.1.0, use the built in Google API. Anything prior to that I would consider adding the universal code yourself.

Comment: Old topic and all but where does the google api logic and code reside? I've turned on GTM and I would like to edit the GTM script to add another parameter. Category ID.